# Transition color attachment from its finalLayout to another layout immediately before the call to vkQueueSubmit

Tags: graphics, vulkan

Say I have a render pass with a single color attachment (corresponding to a swap chain image) whose `VkAttachmentDescription` has `initialLayout = finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL` and (for educational purposes) I want to transition the layout to `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR` after the last drawing command and *immediately* before the call to `vkQueueSubimt` using `vkCmdPipelineBarrier`.

How exactly would I need to do it? I guess that, prior to the call to `vkCmdPipelineBarrier`, I need to call `vkCmdEndRenderPass`, since the render pass will automatically transition to the `finalLayout`, right?

Now, how exactly do I need to set-up the `srcStageMask`, `dstStageMask`, `srcAccessMask` and `dstAccessMask` for the call to `vkCmdEndRenderPass`?

This is still hard to figure out for me (is there a good reference which provides explanations for the "common" transitions?). From the documentation of the API, the right values should be

```
srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;

srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT;
```

However, I receive the following validation error during when calling `vkQueueSubmit`:

> Submitted command buffer expects VkImage 0xd76249000000000c[]
> (subresource: aspectMask 0x1 array layer 0, mip level 0) to be in
> layout VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR--instead, current layout is
> VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED

What's going wrong?

Comment: This question cannot be answered without knowing what layout you're transitioning it to and what you intend to do with the image moving forward.

Comment: @NicolBolas Please take note of my edit.

Comment: "*What's going wrong?*" I don't understand this question. The error *told you* what is "going wrong". The layout of the image is not in the layout you said it would be. That's what went wrong. Fix your code so that the expected layout is the correct layout. And after a half-dozen questions, you *still* haven't explained why it is so important to preserve the contents of a *presented image* at the start of your render pass.

Comment: @NicolBolas I've executed a `vkCmdPipelineBarrier` for that image with the `srcAccessMask`, `dstAccessMask`, `srcStageMask` and `dstStageMask` given in the question. So, I don't understand why the layout is now "undefined".

Comment: We cannot remotely debug your code, especially since we can't see it. I don't know what layout the image was in before the barrier call. But the layer *does*. So you're going to have to debug through your code and find out why the layout isn't what you think it is. Note that the layout is not affected by the source/dest access/stage masks, so telling us what those are is useless.

Answer (score 0):

[Layout transitions at page 33 and further](https://gpuopen.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Most-common-mistakes-in-Vulkan-apps.pdf).

> immediately before the call to `vkQueueSubimt` using `vkCmdPipelineBarrier`

`vkCmd*` functions don't do things immediately. They **record** commands to **a buffer**. You then push the buffer to the GPU queue with `vkQueueSubmit`, so that it does the work in it when it has time.

Also you have to use a `VkImageMemoryBarrier`, inside which you  *specify* image and its layouts.